# What is the alternate/workaround of designer workflow in SharePoint Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-addin

There was a requirement to create workflow in SharePoint Hosted Add-in. Earlier the same flow was implemented on O365 but now the requirement is to achieve the same thing on Add-in.

Is there any way to create workflow in SharePoint Add-in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let me tell you that it is impossible to create Designer Workflows for SharePoint Add In.

Now, you can use Visual Studio for creating workflows.
Also, you can try creating Site Workflows. But this will only work on O365 but not on On Premises as the On Prem Workflow Manager will not be able to relate the workflows of the Add in.

Comment: How Site workflow will help to replicate same flow on Add-in as Add-in will be having separate web. How site workflow will identify add-in Web?

Comment: You will have to create site workflow where you need to write REST API to fetch the list inside Add-In and similarly you can perform the needful actions.